# Hide content if a radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a paragraph if a radio button is checked using a change() function but it's not working. What am I missing?

```
$(".js-rate-type").change(function(){  
    if(this.checked){
      $(".js-rate-type-content").show();
    }else{
      $('.js-rate-type-content').hide();
    }
}).change();
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/2pr3xtxf/9/)**

Comment: for which rate type the content has to be shown?

Comment: The content should show when Daily is checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `change` event handler does not get triggered when you select another radio with the same name, so you need to bind the handle to both the radio buttons

```js
$('input[name="optionsRadios"]').change(function() {
  $(".js-rate-type-content").toggle($('.js-rate-type').is(':checked'));
}).change(); //trigger change to see changes
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <form action="#">

        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="js-rate-type">Daily
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios">Fixed
          </label>
        </div>

      </form>

      <p class="js-rate-type-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to trigger using class name because our project is using dynamic names for radio buttons but I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Bind `change` event to `input[name=optionsRadios]` instead of `.js-rate-type` and toggle `.js-rate-type-content` with the checked status of `.js-rate-type`.

```
$("input[name=optionsRadios]").change(function(){  
    var rateType=$('.js-rate-type')[0];
    $(".js-rate-type-content").toggle(rateType.checked);
}).change()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the jQuery to run/bind by putting it inside a `$(document).ready(function() {});` wrapper.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-rate-type").change(function(){  
        if(this.checked){
        $(".js-rate-type-content").show();
        }else{
          $('.js-rate-type-content').hide();
      }
    }).change(); //trigger change to see changes 
})
```

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me why?

Comment: Yeah of course - essentially, you've written the code, but it won't run because you haven't told it to. jQuery requires that if you want code to run/bind when the user opens the page, you need to tell it: `When the document is ready, do this:`

Comment: I am aware of that but it didn't make any difference =(